# How to send SonarQube report to developers whenever the Azure DevOps build succeeded or failed

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines, sonarqube-scan

I have integrated the SonarQube tasks in Azure DevOps build pipeline. I can be able to successfully the scan my application source code using SonarQube.

I want to share the SonarQube report to Developers whenever the Sonar build succeeded or failed.

Answer (score 1):

For notification settings, first of all, you need to have  mail server or you can use popular ones (Gmail and etc.). Have a look at the below article for the every step you need to perform ;

https://www.fosstechnix.com/sonarqube-email-notifications/

Another possible way is if you have limitations in the Sonarqube server;

1. Create quality gate in Sonarqube based on your profile
   https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/quality-gates/
2. Use following plugin to break your pipeline in case of code were not passed the gate
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimondeLang.sonar-buildbreaker
3. Create mail notification in Azure Devops to send notification when build failed because of Sonarqube quality gate;
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops#team-and-project-level-notifications

And as shown below you will see the reason about  why pipeline build failed in the mail

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Kagan, for your answer. Is it possible to do it in Azure DevOps build pipeline?

Comment: What is possible in the Azure DevOps pipeline? Mail notification and code scans are different concepts. You can scan your code via Azure DevOps and but there is no use case for mail notifications in Azure DevOps for that. There is already a setting in Sonarqube for that

Comment: I want to send mail with SonarQube report via Azure DevOps pipeline. Because due to limited access in SonarQube Server.

Comment: Please see the updated solution

Comment: I want to send an email with SonarQube report via Azure DevOps build pipeline.  Because  the developers want to see the  SonarQube report.  But the developers don't have permission to see the report in SonarQube Server.

Comment: Okay then you need to create really extensive script for that(interact with Sonarqube API ,  create mail body and sent to people). By the way, what is the real reason why people can not see results in Sonarqube ? Sonarqube can give really granular permissions like particular people can just see particular projects